# ahocorasick module problems in linux with Python 2.7

Tags: python, aho-corasick

Recently I am trying to use ahocorasick in centos5.8_x64 with python2.7.5,but I found that the result is abnormal,so would you please tell me the reason?I found the module runs perfectly in my windows 7 with python2.7.5.Here is my test code and result in linux.

```
>>> import ahocorasick
>>> tree=ahocorasick.KeywordTree()
>>> tree.add("id")
>>> tree.make()
>>> tree.search("sdfsdf fsfsdf")
>>> tree.search("sdfsdf fsfsdf")
(240103, 240105)
>>> tree.search("sdfsdf fsfsdf")
(240103, 240105)
>>>
```

The return values should be None,but I don't know why the return values seems to be a overflow number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Centos6.4 to solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

I encountered exactly the same issue. It should be the defect of the module. After all, it hasn't been modified since 2005. I used https://code.google.com/p/esmre/ instead. It worked find. Give it a trial!